# rsync exclude not working in shell script

Tags: shell-script

I have this minimal working example of shell script that won't exclude cache directory.

```
#!/bin/sh

SRC_DIR="/home/"
DEST_DIR="/backup/test"
OPTSTR="-avzHAXx --delete --exclude '.cache'"

rsync $OPTSTR $SRC_DIR $DEST_DIR
```

But, if you write that open, then it works.

```
#!/bin/sh

rsync -avzHAXx --delete --exclude '.cache' /home/ /backup/test
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue has to do with the way you use your string `$OPTSTR`.  This is a string of multiple space-separated words, and since you use it unquoted, you make the shell split it into a list of separate words.  However, the shell will not perform an extra quote removal step, so the single quotes in the string will be *literal*.  You command therefore excludes files and directories named `'.cache'`, not `.cache`.  You would also have issue had you needed to use strings with spaces in them, or globbing patterns.

In short:  Do not put separate things, that needs to be kept separate, in a single string.

Instead, use a list:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

src_dir=/home
dest_dir=/backup/test

set -- -v -a -x -HAX --delete --exclude='.cache/'

rsync "$@" "$src_dir/" "$dest_dir"
```

This sets the list of positional parameters to the options that you later want to use with `rsync`.  Each parameter will be correctly handled, even if it contains quoted string with embedded spaces and globbing characters, as long as the expansion of `$@` is double quoted.

Or, if you use `bash`, you may use a named array,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

src_dir=/home
dest_dir=/backup/test

opts=( -v -a -x -HAX --delete --exclude='.cache/' )

rsync "${opts[@]}" "$src_dir/" "$dest_dir"
```

Also related:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946)